Nginx RTMP on_publish Not Triggering API Endpoint on Next.js Server
I am facing an issue where Nginx's RTMP on_publish directive does not seem to trigger my API endpoint hosted on a Next.js server (Vercel), despite the endpoint working correctly with manual POST requests via Postman. The Nginx server is configured to send a POST request to the Next.js API when a stream starts, but these requests are not being logged or processed by the Next.js server.
Issue:

Manual POST requests to the endpoint via Postman successfully update the database.

Requests from Nginx using the on_publish directive don't seem to reach the Next.js API; they're    neither logged in Vercel's dashboard nor do they update the database.

Nginx logs do not show relevant errors, and testing the endpoint via curl from the Nginx server returns a "Redirecting..." message.


Environment:

Nginx with libnginx-mod-rtmp module ( https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#on_publish )

Next.js application hosted on Vercel

API endpoint designed to update MongoDB Atlas upon receiving data


Nginx Configuration (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf):
rtmp {
        server {

                listen 1935;
                # ... configs
                # ...

                application live {

                        live on;
                        record off;

                        on_publish http://example.com/api/stream/startStream?streamKey=test;
                        on_publish_done http://example.com/api/stream/endStream?streamKey=test;
                 }
        }
}


Next.js API Endpoint (/api/stream/startStream):
export async function POST(
  req: NextRequest
): Promise<NextResponse<ResponseData>> {
  try {
  
// Connect to database 

... 

// Receive streamKey to store in database

    const streamKey = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("streamKey");

    if (!streamKey) {
      return NextResponse.json({
        msg: "Streamkey is not defined",
        data: false,
      });
    }

// Store streamKey in database
    
    const insertedStreamKey = await connectedStreams.insertOne({
      streamKey: streamKey,
    });

    if (!insertedStreamKey) {
   
      return NextResponse.json({
        msg: "Streamkey couldn't be inserted!",
        data: false,
      });
    }

    return NextResponse.json({
      msg: "User is successfully connected",

      data: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
   ...
  }
}



Verified the Nginx on_publish URL ( Postman works fine and is visible in my API Logs ).

Tested direct requests from the Nginx server using curl.

Checked for network issues, SSL/TLS misconfigurations, and redirection behaviors.



I have also stuck at this problem for a long time. Finally I find out that there're some troubles on my Nginx RTMP that it cannot resolve the ip address from a host name. After I replaced localhost with 127.0.0.1, everything turned well.
